# IBM Worklight 6.0 - Calling WL.Client.Login in a native Android app

Tags: java, android, ibm-mobilefirst

The Javascript Worklight API has a method `WL.Client.login` which sends a request to the Worklight Server and initiates an authentication challenge.

What is the equivalent method in the native Worklight Android Java API?

I have gone through all the docs and can not find it. The only way to start an authentication challenge is to make a call to a protected adapter procedure which isn't ideal in some scenarios.

Does such a method exist, or possibly an alternative approach?

Comment: IBMWorklight assumes a lot about Android. Not all is tested.

Answer (score 1):

WL.Client.login(realm, options) in javascript sends a request to a specific realm and triggers its challenges.
This method **does not** exist in the WLClient Java api.
So the way to start the authentication process in Java is either by invoking a protected adapter, or by connecting to a protected application - but currently you cannot login to a specific realm in the Java api.

Comment: Ok so our application currently uses 2 realms to authenticate in a single security test from JS. How would we go about doing the same in native Android Java?

Comment: any ideas? Or anyone else?

Comment: Could you please elaborate on the flow you are running? are the resources the app uses (adapters) on the server protected by these same tests? or are the tests only on the login?  You don't have to first login and then for example invokeProcedure, you could simply invokeProcedure on a protected procedure, and it will start the challenge handling flow, same way as the login would